# Writing Fit/Fitnesse tests using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, fitnesse

I am really new to *Fit/Fitnesse* and, in general, to test automation.
I am trying to use them from *Eclipse*.

I have several question about it:

1. is there a way to obtain the html tables that Fitnesse pass to Fit?
2. once I write several tests with Fitnesse, is there a way to call them several times from Java without clicking on the Test button of the wiki?
3. About passing objects from one table to another in a flow. I read about symbols but it seems that, in java, they works only with `ColumnFixture`while I would like to use `DoFixture`. how to do this?

Finally,is if there is any plugin for eclipse you suggest to use with Fit/Fitnesse?

Comment: That is 3 questions, not one.

Comment: Ok, sorry.
Consider just question number 3.

Comment: Rather than commenting, just edit your question.

Comment: Have you looked at Slim? Given you are new to this I would suggest to investigate whether you can use that test engine which gets more active development.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you question 2: I would recommend using the JUnit integration `(@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)` to run the test page (or a suite) as a unit test from Eclipse. This also gives you the ability to debug inside your fixture code.

It takes a bit of configuration to get it running 'just right'. In [my pre-packaged FitNesse](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures) I provide a unit test `FixtureDebug` where you only have to enter the test name (and you can also use that to run your tests on a build/continuous integration server).